# How to write exceptions (class x throws y)

Tags: java, exception, throws

I have code here which runs a short series of tests to see if the last element in the array is the expected number.  The code that I have to put in goes where [???] is currently.

```
   //The answer must be the shortest possible
class EmptyArrayException extends RuntimeException{}
class ArrayUtil{
  public static Object lastElement (Object[]array)[???]{
    if(array.length>0)return array[array.length-1];
    throw new EmptyArrayException();
  }
}
public class Exercise{
  public static void test(){
    assert ArrayUtil.lastElement(new Integer[]{1,2,3}).equals(3);
    assert ArrayUtil.lastElement(new Integer[]{1,2}).equals(2);
    assert ArrayUtil.lastElement(new Integer[]{1}).equals(1);
    assert ArrayUtil.lastElement(new Integer[]{}).equals(1);
    assert false:"Code not reachable";
  }
  public static void main(String [] arg){
    try{ test();}
    catch(Throwable t){/*the test suit
      logs t on the test results: 
      a single place for error logging.*/}
  }
}
```

I assume that I would write ' throws EmptyArrayException ', but this is wrong.   ' throws EmptyArrayException() ' is wrong too.

So what do I put in the [???] space?

Comment: If an exception type is a subtype of `RuntimeException`, you don't need to specify it in the `throws` clause.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Did you perhaps surrounded `throws EmptyArrayException` with `[` `]`?

Comment: `throws EmptyArrayException` is the correct syntax.  What do you mean by "but this is wrong"?  Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: For the shortest possible? Nothing. You would put nothing there. If you weren't throwing a RuntimeException, you would needs a `throws` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your exception is a `RuntimeException` you don't need to specify anything. However you can. Sometimes I do it in an effort to document that such method might throw a certain exception.

```
public static Object lastElement (Object[]array) throws EmptyArrayException
```

It is up to you.

Comment: Why is the answer nearly always simple?